# Re-requisites for publishing iBeacon Android app on google play store

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I have developed an Android app which has implementation of iBeacon Technology.

The app detects one specific UUID type of beacons and proceeds further. These beacons has set of actions defined on CMS.

I want to submit the same to google play store but not sure about checklist i should follow before putting it on store.

So what are the pre-requisites or steps to be followed to submit iBeacon app to google play store ? Also do i need to provide CMS login during submission for google app testers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no special requirements for submitting a beacon app to the Google Play Store.  Unlike Apple's App Store, apps are not manually tested after submission.  They are merely scanned for malicious code.

Simply submit the app and if it passes this scan, you will be told in a matter of seconds if it is approved.